# Finding the right unlimited strength files

Tags: java, security, cryptography, lotus

I am trying to solve error

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters
```

on this version of java: on domino server 8.5.1

```
java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pwa6460sr4-20090219_01(SR4))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, J2RE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Windows Vista amd64-64 jvmwa6460-200
90215_29883 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20090215_029883_LEdSMr
JIT  - r9_20090213_2028
GC   - 20090213_AA)
JCL  - 20090218_01
```

From my research I should overwrite files local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar. But Sun files do not work and links to IMB files are broken. Can someone tell me where to find those files and which ones to use for this version of java.

Comment: You probably need to open a PMR (Support call with IBM). You can't just overwrite files in the Domino JVM. Even if it worked, you are in an unsupported/untested configuration and could break any number of things.

Comment: Hi user2323513, and welcome. I agree with the above assesment by Simon, but to close the question for this reason is taking it a bit too far. This is not a "favorite resource" or anything like that. 
user2323513, you could try both ways and post a solution if you get something back from IBM. Maybe somebody knows a workaround here?

Answer (score 1):

I have foud it. IBM files work they are at

https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/iwm/web/preLogin.do?source=jcesdk

for this version of java older files work,